# About Consistency on Audits - Review Audit Failed Case

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I have experienced this situation multiples times already.

It is related to doing a review for Late Answers or for First Posts, where the content includes a Link-Only answer.

Then in presence of uncertain, I used these two criteria:

1. I used to evaluate the consistency looking for similar answers into the original question's body or
2. if in my opinion,  the inclusion of a summary or introduction, related to the link is redundant or does not matter, then I consider that the answer can be considerate as valid. (especially for new users that do not have enough score to comment)

For example, In the question: [What is the android.widget.Toast equivalent for iOS applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522866/android-toast-in-iphone)

I have been tested with:

[image: late answer review audit failure]

So looking the body of the question and its accepted/voted answers, I could see similar answers with positive votes, like these:

[image: examples of upvoted answers]

That made me think, the review as valid, But at the end, as you can see in the first image, my review was evaluated as a fail.

So, can I conclude that Stack Overflow principles about not accepting link-only answers is more significant than the real utility of the answer itself?

Comment: Mmmmm, toast...

Answer (score 11):

Link-only answers are generally frowned upon, and you should flag them if you come across them in the First Posts queue (in the Low Quality Posts queue, we have a specific deletion reason for them).

In general, however, you may come across audits that you are not happy with because they are picked automatically (humans are not involved), so if you disagree with one, you can prevent it from becoming an audit again by going to that post and taking the opposite action (if it's a "positive audit," like this one, downvote it, and if it's a negative one, upvote it).

As for the highly-upvoted answers you see on that post, they're historically inflated: over time, as people have come across that question (often via Google), they have upvoted answers that led them to an answer. Also, the question is pretty old, and guidelines for answers have changed since then, so there were probably a significant amount of upvotes from the initial posting.

Answer (score 5):

> Goto This link simple method to show android like toast in iphone

This contains no information is thus not an answer.

> If anyone is interested, I made a very simple straight forward Toast class to be added to your project.
>
> Ridiculously easy to use

This contains no information is thus not an answer.

> To follow up on this the project has been added to github
>
> so fork it baby fork it....

This contains no information is thus not an answer.

> you can use this link to achieve the android like toast messages in iOS

This contains no information is thus not an answer.

> This solution is also useful

This contains no information is thus not an answer.

Why aren't they deleted? Well… have you flagged them all?

Comment: and "you can use this link to achieve the android like toast messages in iOS " contains more? the OP is asking why is the first one NOT an answer when the others are.

Comment: @Patrice Who says the other ones are?

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate here. The OP is asking why he's failing an audit while similar answers are not similarly deleted. I understand your point and for the record, I do think like you. I am just trying to see how your answer is helping the OP asking why some answers are deleted and not others.

Comment: @Patrice Siiigh, ok. (edited)

Comment: `is is` copy/pasta, heh.